# Illustrator scripting: resize that works like transform tool in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

I'm writing a script for Illustrator CS5 to resize my artwork (and artboards and a whole lot of other stuff in a batch).

I'm having severe issues with the javascript functions resize() and transform().
When I scale my object manually inside Illustrator (double clicking on the scale tool or using the transform dialog), I can select "Scale Stroke and Effects" and scaling looks fine.

I scale this down to 20%:

[image: Original]:

And I get this (which is fine):

[image: Scaled with scale dialog]

Now, when I use the resize() or transform() functions in Illustrator's scripting I get this:

[image: Scaled with script]

The simple script to reproduce:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var item = doc.pageItems[0];
item.resize(
    20.0, // x
    20.0, // y
    true, // changePositions
    true, // changeFillPatterns
    true, // changeFillGradients
    true, // changeStrokePattern
    true , // changeLineWidths
    undefined); // scaleAbout
```

I have tried playing around with the parameters to resize() but nothing comes close to the transform dialog in Illustrator.

The original .ai file can be downloaded [from here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/48764234/illustrator_scripting_scaling.ai).

So my question is: How can I get the same effect from javascript as I can from using the built in transform dialog ?

Answer (score 10):

Turns out that the (badly named IMHO) "changeLineWidths" parameter is not a boolean but a scaling factor just like the x and y parameters.

So this is solved like this:

```
var scale = 20; // scale down to 20%
item.resize(
    scale , // x
    scale , // y
    true, // changePositions
    true, // changeFillPatterns
    true, // changeFillGradients
    true, // changeStrokePattern
    scale , // changeLineWidths    <----  NOTE THIS
    undefined); // scaleAbout
```

(IMHO "changeLineWidths" should be named "scaleLineWidths" just like the first two are named "scaleX" and "scaleY" in the [documentation](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/illustrator/scripting/illustrator_scripting_reference_javascript_cs5.pdf).)

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Good point about the name of `changeLineWidths`.